# Are logs included while creating the dot file in gstreamer?

Tags: debugging, gstreamer, graphviz, xdotool

I am trying to understand, how dot file is created from gstreamer logs.
When I generated the gstreamer logs with `GST_DEBUG=4` it generated huge number of logs.
At the same time when I check the dot file generated by gstreamer, it has specific information about the pipeline creation. Not the log information after pipeline is created like playing paused seeking...

I have some questions:

1. What information will be having in dot file when compared to complete log file?
2. If all the logs are not included in dot file, then how we can debug those log information using dotgraph(using tools like graphviz)?

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

1. The `dot` file is a graphical representation of your complete pipeline, the interconnection of different elements in the pipeline along with the information about the caps negotiation. For eg. When your pipeline grows too large, and you need information about the connection of different elements and the flow of data, usage of `dot` files will prove useful. Follow this [link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html#getting-pipeline-graphs).
2. With `GST_DEBUG=4`, all the logs, warnings, errors of different elements will be outputted. This is particularly useful when you want to understand the lower levels of what is going on inside the elements when the dataflow  occurs along the pipeline. You can get information about different events, pad information, buffer information ,etc.  Follow this [link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html#printing-debug-information).

To get more information about a specific element you could also use the following:
`GST_DEBUG=<element_name>:4`

Comment: Got it!! Thanks for the answer.